# provisioning profile and signing certificate for a group of individual developers

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm pretty new to ios development. Me and a group of people are trying to work on a project, but we keep getting merge conflicts for the signing profiles and signing certificates.

I understand that I can create an "organization" apple developer account and link developer accounts; however, we currently do not have paid developer accounts.

I was wondering if there is anyway to set up the profiles such that we dont have so many conflicts merging and rebasing.

Comment: That is a very common error/verdict, the reason is xcode automatically generate provisioning profile therefore different signing cert. if you dont use the same developers account developing, using same developer account works well for me when I work and pulling codes at home.